# ASP.Net Boilerplate get entity after create

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using AsyncCrudAppService Create method for creating entity. Call create method from controller, get newly created entity id, then call Get method of AsyncCrudAppService. But returned data don't sets related entities. I'm having this problem only in this scenario, i mean when i call GetAll(), Get() in other scenarios i'm not getting this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The newly created entity is available after you call `SaveChanges` method of your unit of work.

```
var record = new Record() { Name = "lorem ipsum" };
_recordRepository.Insert(record);
CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

After that, if you put debugger breakpoint and hover `record` variable - it is already loaded as DB record.